# Script Rename of SQL Server Database and Database Files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

As part of our development lifecycle, we would like to do regular comparisons of versions of our database between two different versions of source control.

I expect that there are many automated solutions to do this, but right now we do the following:

1. Update repository to a particular version
2. In Visual Studio

   1. Build solution
   2. Build database
3. In SSMS

   1. Rename database
   2. Detach database
4. In File Explorer

   1. Rename database files
5. In SSMS

   1. Attach database
6. Repeat steps 1-5 for another version
7. Compare the two databases with SqlCompare

It would be very helpful if we could script all of steps 3-5 (as they're currently done via GUI), probably as a TSQL script, but we'd be open to other options. Can this be done easily?

Comment: That could quite easily be automated through PowerShell.  Using SMO, the SQL work is concise and straightforward, and then the rename of the database files is a one-liner.

Comment: Since you're using VStudio, I assume you're using SSDT?  Any reason you wouldn't compare the schemas via .dacpac?  You can use Powershell+Powershell to extract your .dacpacs and then compare them in VStudio.  You can skip all the database file copying nonsense.

Comment: @MikeFal, we're using Fluent Migrator, so we don't have .dacpac files.